# MySQL update function (I don't want to update blank fields, but all other)

Tags: php, mysql

Basically: I got `EditProfile.php` with form(to change profile data), If all fields are chosen it works perfectly.

Problem: I want to update only that fields, that aren't blank.
For example `Image` (Update only if file, has been uploaded.) AND `gender` (Update only if option has been selected.) **At this moment, it updates these two fields to blank (delete's Image patch and gender option).**

[image]

And Error with second version:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''username' = CASE WHEN 'Crelix' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(Crelix)) = 0 THEN 'b' at line 2
```

Sending Form data to different file function.

```
if (isset($_POST['edit-btn'])) {
    $id = strip_tags($_POST['id']);
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)) {
        $image = '../Images/Users/Gallery/' . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
    $firstname = strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);
    $surname = strip_tags($_POST['surname']);
    $gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);
    $birthday = strip_tags($_POST['birthday']);
    $carsowned = strip_tags($_POST['carsowned']);
    $homepage = strip_tags($_POST['homepage']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
    $education = strip_tags($_POST['education']);
    $profession = strip_tags($_POST['profession']);
    $work = strip_tags($_POST['work']);
    $facebook = strip_tags($_POST['facebook']);
    $instagram = strip_tags($_POST['instagram']);
    $twitter = strip_tags($_POST['twitter']);
    $vk = strip_tags($_POST['vk']);
    $bio = strip_tags($_POST['bio']);
    $interests = strip_tags($_POST['interests']);

    $user->editProfile($id,$username,$email,$password,$image,$firstname,$surname,$gender,$birthday,$carsowned,$homepage,$phone,$education,$profession,$work,
                    $facebook,$instagram,$twitter,$vk,$bio,$interests);
}
```

And Update function: (Got 2 versions) No one works.

My Own Version:

```
    public function editProfile($id,$username,$email,$password,$image,$firstname,$surname,$gender,$birthday,$carsowned,$homepage,$phone,$education,$profession,$work,
                    $facebook,$instagram,$twitter,$vk,$bio,$interests){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET id=:id,username=:username,email=:email,password=:password,image=:image,firstname=:firstname,surname=:surname,
        gender=:gender,birthday=:birthday,carsowned=:carsowned,homepage=:homepage,phone=:phone,education=:education,profession=:profession,work=:work,facebook=:facebook,instagram=:instagram,
        twitter=:twitter,vk=:vk,bio=:bio,interests=:interests WHERE id=('$id')");

        $stmt->bindparam(":id", $id);
        $stmt->bindparam(":username", $username);
        $stmt->bindparam(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindparam(":password", $password);
        $stmt->bindparam(":image", $image);
        $stmt->bindparam(":firstname", $firstname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":surname", $surname);
        $stmt->bindparam(":gender", $gender);
        $stmt->bindparam(":birthday", $birthday);
        $stmt->bindparam(":carsowned", $carsowned);
        $stmt->bindparam(":homepage", $homepage);
        $stmt->bindparam(":phone", $phone);
        $stmt->bindparam(":education", $education);
        $stmt->bindparam(":profession", $profession);
        $stmt->bindparam(":work", $work);
        $stmt->bindparam(":facebook", $facebook);
        $stmt->bindparam(":instagram", $instagram);
        $stmt->bindparam(":twitter", $twitter);
        $stmt->bindparam(":vk", $vk);
        $stmt->bindparam(":bio", $bio);
        $stmt->bindparam(":interests", $interests);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Reading and searching online for help, made something like this, but nothing changes:

```
public function editProfile($id,$username,$email,$password,$image,$firstname,$surname,$gender,$birthday,$carsowned,$homepage,$phone,$education,$profession,$work,
                    $facebook,$instagram,$twitter,$vk,$bio,$interests){
    try{
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET
        '$username' = CASE WHEN '$username' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($username)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$username' END,
        '$email' = CASE WHEN '$email' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($email)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$email' END,
        '$password' = CASE WHEN '$password' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($password)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$password' END,
        '$image' = CASE WHEN '$image' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($image)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$image' END,
        '$firstname' = CASE WHEN '$firstname' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($firstname)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$firstname' END,
        '$surname' = CASE WHEN '$surname' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($surname)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$surname' END,
        '$gender' = CASE WHEN '$gender' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($gender)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$gender' END,
        '$birthday' = CASE WHEN '$birthday' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($birthday)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$birthday' END,
        '$carsowned' = CASE WHEN '$carsowned' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($carsowned)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$carsowned' END,
        '$homepage' = CASE WHEN '$homepage' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($homepage)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$homepage' END,
        '$phone' = CASE WHEN '$phone' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($phone)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$phone' END,
        '$education' = CASE WHEN '$education' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($education)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$education' END,
        '$profession' = CASE WHEN '$profession' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($profession)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$profession' END,
        '$work' = CASE WHEN '$work' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($work)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$work' END,
        '$facebook' = CASE WHEN '$facebook' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($facebook)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$facebook' END,
        '$instagram' = CASE WHEN '$instagram' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($instagram)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$instagram' END,
        '$twitter' = CASE WHEN '$twitter' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($twitter)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$twitter' END,
        '$vk' = CASE WHEN '$vk' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($vk)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$vk' END,
        '$bio' = CASE WHEN '$bio' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($bio)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$bio' END,
        '$interests' = CASE WHEN '$interests' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($interests)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$interests' END,

    WHERE `id` = '".$id."' ");
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Version 3. Still same problem

```
public function editProfile($id,$username,$email,$password,$image,$firstname,$surname,$gender,$birthday,
        $carsowned,$homepage,$phone,$education,$profession,$work,$facebook,$instagram,$twitter,$vk,
        $bio,$interests){
    try{

            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET
            username = IF(:username != '', :username, username),
            email = IF(:email != '', :email, email),
            password = IF(:password != '', :password, password),
                image = IF(:image != '', :image, image),
                firstname = IF(:firstname != '', :firstname, firstname),
            surname = IF(:surname != '', :surname, surname),
            gender = IF(:gender != '', :gender, gender),
                birthday = IF(:birthday != '', :birthday, birthday),
                carsowned = IF(:carsowned != '', :carsowned, carsowned),
            homepage = IF(:homepage != '', :homepage, homepage),
            phone = IF(:phone != '', :phone, phone),
                education = IF(:education != '', :education, education),
                profession = IF(:profession != '', :profession, profession),
            work = IF(:work != '', :work, work),
            facebook = IF(:facebook != '', :facebook, facebook),
                instagram = IF(:instagram != '', :instagram, instagram),
                twitter = IF(:twitter != '', :twitter, twitter),
            vk = IF(:vk != '', :vk, vk),
            bio = IF(:bio != '', :bio, bio),
                interests = IF(:interests != '', :interests, interests),
            WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Errors in these lines:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)) {
            $image = '../Images/Users/Gallery/' . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        }

$gender = strip_tags($_POST['gender']);

$user->editProfile($id,$username,$email,$password,$image,$firstname,$surname,$gender,$birthday,$carsowned,$homepage,$phone,$education,$profession,$work,
                        $facebook,$instagram,$twitter,$vk,$bio,$interests);
```

Comment: The left side of `=` has to be the column name you want to fill in, not a string.

Comment: @Barmar With second code I get this error "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''username' = CASE WHEN 'Crelix' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(Crelix)) = 0 THEN 'b' at line 2"

Comment: That's what I said, you can't assign to a literal string, you have to assign to a column name.

Comment: @Barmar I changed left collumn without "$" If I understood right, still same error: "'username' = CASE WHEN '$username' IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM($username)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE '$username' END,"

Comment: the problem is the quotes, not the `$`. You can't assign to `'username'`, you have to assign to the column name `username`.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: You also shouldn't store password in plain text, you should use `password_hash()`.

Comment: Why are u prepending `$` to the column names?

Comment: @Barmar You think like this, right? "$new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);"

Comment: yes, like that. There are many questions here and tutorials elsewhere about the proper way to store passwords in databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF()` expressions that return the value if it's not empty, otherwise the old value of the column.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET 
    username = IF(:username != '', :username, username),
    email = IF(:email != '', :email, email),
    password = IF(:password != '', :password, password),
    ...
    WHERE id = :id");
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to set the `id` column, since that's the column you're matching in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out right now. If it works, will be really gratefull.

Comment: You're missing all the calls to `$stmt->bindParam()`.